# Magento 1.9 - Get attributes per group (nearly there!)

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, attribute-group

I'm trying to get the attributes in the layered navigation to show per group. On default, they show per seperate attribute option like so

```
Walls
   Walls (12)

Ceilings
   Ceilings (14)

Wood
   Wood (5)
```

While in the backend, in the attribute group, all these attributes are grouped in a group called 'Application'. I want to call the layered navigation per those groups so that it appears as:

```
Application
   Walls (12)
   Ceilings (14)
   Wood (5)
```

I feel like I'm halfway there. I got this code to show the groups (with name and ID) and in there the attribute codes are called:

```
    $groups = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')
        ->getResourceCollection()
        ->setAttributeSetFilter(4) // Attribute set Id
        ->setSortOrder()
        ->load();

    $attributeCodes = array();
    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        $groupName = $group->getAttributeGroupName();
        $groupId   = $group->getAttributeGroupId();

        $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
            ->setAttributeGroupFilter($group->getId())
            ->addVisibleFilter()
            ->checkConfigurableProducts()
            ->load();


        if ($groupId == 43) { // Get group 'Application'
            if ($attributes->getSize() > 0) {
                echo '<strong>'.$groupName.'</strong><br>';
                foreach ($attributes->getItems() as $attribute) {
                    /* @var $child Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute */
                    $attributeCodes[] = $attribute->getAttributeCode();    
                    echo $attribute->getName(); echo '<br>';
                }
            } 
        }
```

This shows the attribute codes for the group Application, but just those. I'm unclear how to get the actual filter code there.

In the default way where the filters are shown functional (tied in with Ajax filtering and all that);

```
            <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
            <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
            <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                <?php 
                $source = $_filter->getFilter()->getRequestVar();
                ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $source ?>">
                <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

So the question is; how do I get able to call the `$_filter->getHtml()` inside the `foreach ($groups as $group)`? I tried simply using `$attribute->getHtml()` etc, but that was a long shot and doesn't work.